# Multiple versions of PHP and Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I have some version php and I need install mongo for 5.6 version. Early I have mongo for 5.5 version
and now intsall

```
ivan@ivan-PC:/usr/lib/php$ sudo pecl install mongodb
pecl/mongodb is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.1.9
install failed

sudo pecl install mongo
pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.14
```

install failed

and when I check php -m I dont see mongo and in phpinfo not find mongo. Try like this

```
phpenmod -v php5.6 mongodb
```

but inthis way

```
/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/
```

have

```
mongo.ini
```

whe run php -m not have mongo module

```
sudo pecl info mongo
About pecl.php.net/mongo-1.6.14
```

But still not mongo for my version php. How to right enable mongo for another php version ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to required php version with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config=php
sudo update-alternatives --config=php-config
sudo update-alternatives --config=phpize
```

Just run install with force flag

```
sudo pecl install -f mongodb
```